# MQTT in php on shared hosting

Tags: c#, php, mqtt

I'm developing a web app in php which will tell a desktop service built in C# to do something based on the command i sent from php, so i used mqtt to publish message (command) from php to C#, but on shared hosting i can't connect to mqtt broker (external broker) on port 1883.

this is the error

> unable to connect to tcp://externalBroker:1883 (Connection refused).

the php app is hosted on web (shared hosting) and the desktop service is on my laptop.

is there any solution for this problem, or any alternative way to send message from php to c#?

Comment: Where exactly is the MQTT broker?

Comment: It's outside my hosting, my host server is blocking port 1883

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by updating my hosting from shared to VPS and i installed my own Broker,

also connection was refused because i was not allowed to open port 1883 so you can buy a dedicated ip and you will be able to open ports.

this are the solution i found and i used the first one (upgrading to VPS).

hope this will help other people whose gonna face the same problem.